# How to use UIViewController in Safari Extension App on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, safari-extension

Xcode offers a predefined target called *Safari Extension App* for both iOS and macOS:
[image: Target iOS]
[image: Target macOS]

But it seems to be completely different from each other. On macOS I can create a toolbar button that displays a popup view that contains a [`NSViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariextensionhandling/1690338-popoverviewcontroller). On iOS however, the only way to create a popup view is using `HTML` and `JavaScript`.

Is there any way to use a `UIViewController` on iOS instead?

It appears that the Safari App Extensions API is only accessible on macOS. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions

Am I missing something?